# Как добавить <script></script> в тег <body> на сайт,написанный на Python

Tags: python

Всем привет, есть сайт-магазин на Python,нужно тупо добавить написанный скрипт в конец тега body этого сайта, но я настолько далек от Питона, что даже не представляю как и куда зайти, что бы добавить скрипт(я в отчаянии,пожалуйста помогите
До этого сайта,просто подключался по ftp и там в исходном файле, что нужно добавлял и редактировал..

Comment: Спрашивайте у того, кто делал сайт

Comment: К сожалению там концы потеряны, того разраба не найти, есть только сайт и доступ к "администрирование Django"

Comment: Тогда искать нового работника который умеет работать с Django

Comment: А без знания Django,просто скопировать и вставить готовый скрипт проблема?(

Comment: Если разработчик сайта не предусмотрел это, то проблема. А предусмотрел ли — спрашивайте у того, кто делал сайт ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

1. Наиболее вероятно у Вас в проекте есть папка templates там будут шаблоны c html кодом, найдите базовый(в котором прописан тег body). Далее все как в HTML.
2. В папке проекта сделай поиск по содержимому файлов: . А дальше перебором. Главное сделайте резервную копию. Удобный поиск есть в sublime text как пример.